# open single form array control in material modal using Reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

i am facing an issue, i am building a from with list of students ( formarray ). when clicked on edit of a single form array control, i want to open material modal to edit those fields & complete the student information. The issue i am facing is that as modal fields are not part of formgroup, its giving an error. How can i use 1 single control in that modal.

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="container">
    <div formArrayName="students">
        <button type="button" (click)="addStudent()"> Add </button>
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let control of students.controls; let i = index">
            <!-- All other fields -->

            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="openModal(studentModal, i)">
            close </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #studentModal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="material-icons">{{'close' | translate}}</i></span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="border-apply">
          <div class="m-b-20">
              <div class="contact-grid">
                <!-- Display single formarray control -->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Meanwhile component class is

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    students: this.fb.array([])
});

get students(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('students') as FormArray;
}

addStudent(): void {
    this.sensors.push(this.fb.group({
        studentUniqueID: new FormControl(),
        name: new FormControl(''),
        grade: new FormControl('')
      }),
    ]));
}


openModal(content, id): void {
  this.toEditStudentControl = this.students.controls[id];
  this.editIndex = id;
  this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'sm' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "data" to pass the formGroup

If you has a .html like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="students">
    <div
      *ngFor="let group of students.controls;let i=index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <input formControlName="name" />

      <!--see you pass to openDialog, the template and the index-->
      <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(template,i)">Open dialog</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<!--see the "let-data"-->
<ng-template #template let-data>
    <form [formGroup]="data.group">
    <input formControlName="name">
</form>
<!--see that in close we return the data.group.value-->

<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.group.value" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</ng-template>
```

This allow you use some like

```
/**WRONG APROACH**/
openDialog(template:any,index:number) {
    const dialogRef=this.dialog.open(template, {
      data: {
        group: this.students.at(index),
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      (this.students.at(index) as FormGroup).patchValue(result)
    });
  }
```

See that the formArray has already change, but it's necesary use a patchValue to show the data in the input.

Well, really it's not a good idea pass the formGroup else a copy. So, if we cancel our FormArray not change

So, we are changing a bit your function addStudent and split in addStudent and createStudent

```
  addStudent()
  {
    this.students.push(this.createStudent());
  }
  createStudent(data: any = null): FormGroup {
    data = data || { studentUniqueID: 0, name: '', grade: '' };
    return new FormGroup({
      studentUniqueID: new FormControl(data.studentUniqueID),
      name: new FormControl(data.name),
      grade: new FormControl(data.grade),
    });
  }
```

Now, our openDialog becomes like

```
  /*GOOD APPROACH**/
  openDialog(template: any, index: number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(template, {
      data: {
        group: this.createStudent(this.students.at(index).value),
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      (this.students.at(index) as FormGroup).patchValue(result);
    });
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8tav1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-data-example.ts)

IMPORTANT NOTE: Really If we only want to change the elements in the dialog, really don't need a FormArray. We can use a simple array of objects

```
<div *ngFor="let st of studentList;let i=index">
    name:{{st.name}}<button mat-button (click)="openDialog2(template,i)">Open dialog</button>
</div>
openDialog2(template: any, index: number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(template, {
      data: {
        group: this.createStudent(this.students.at(index).value),
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      this.studentList[index]=result;
    });
  }
```

Comment: **DISCLAMER**: :(, I don't read the question propertly. The solution is add the FormControl to the element of FormArray (and pass the control as data not the formArray.at(index)). You needn't create an input to this formControl, a formArray or a FormGroup exist independient the .html. I don't remove the answer to can help in another similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "data" to pass the control or create a new control with the data (see the reason in the another response)

```
<ng-template #template let-data>
    <input [formControl]="data.control" />
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.control.value" cdkFocusInitial>
    Ok
  </button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template let-data>
    <input [formControl]="data.control" />
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.control.value" cdkFocusInitial>
    Ok
  </button>
</ng-template>
```

The .ts:

```
  openDialog(template: any, index: number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(template, {
      data: {
        control: new FormControl(this.students.at(index).get('address')?.value),
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      const control=this.students.at(index).get('address');
      control && control.patchValue(result);
    });
  }
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8tav1g-gabljz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-data-example.ts)

NOTE: Also you can pass only a variable and use ngModel

```
<ng-template #template2 let-data>
<input [(ngModel)]="data.value" />
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.value" cdkFocusInitial>
Ok
</button>
</ng-template>

  openDialog2(template: any, index: number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(template, {
      data: {
        value: this.students.at(index).get('address')?.value,
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      const control=this.students.at(index).get('address');
      control && control.patchValue(result);
    });
  }
```